# How to initialise ObjectInputStream with some value in it? (not null)

Tags: java, initialization, inputstream, objectinputstream

I have initialised `InputStreamReader` with a byte Array and then initialized `ObjectOutputStream` passing it to it's constructor. But it shows error: `invalid stream Header`. Please help on how to give some value to `ObjectInputStream`.

Comment: Is the byte array being passed to the InputStream a valid, serialized java object?

Comment: Have you got any code?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't confused ObjectOutputStream with ObjectInputStream ? Your question is not being consistent with itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ObjectStreams` have a very specific format, so you can't just create a byte array and expect it to be in the correct format. You can write objects to a byte array by using `ObjectOutputStream` and that will ensure the correct format.

```
// Write an object to a ByteArrayOutputStream
ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(bout);
oout.writeObject(someObject);
oout.close();

// Read the object from the resulting array
ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bout.toByteArray()));
oin.readObject(); // Read the object we wrote in
```

Comment: Thanks :) that did it.